# Set-ExecutionPolicy for hundreds of users with PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, admin

I am trying to set the execution policy for more than 150 users.... I wrote a script, ***it runs with out error***, but I confirmed with the user that ***the change wasn't made***...

```
$worstationobject = New-Object psobject Hostname

Add-Member -InputObject $worstationobject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CORP\mkatherine'  -Value 'FooBar23'
Add-Member -InputObject $worstationobject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CORP\jshmoe'  -Value 'FooBar12'


function Get-MemberValues {
   $wslist = $worstationobject.psobject.Members |
   ? {$_.Membertype -eq "noteproperty"} | 
   %{ $_.Value }
   $wslist -join ","
}
function Set-ThePolicies {
   $devices = Get-MemberValues
   Invoke-Command -InputObject $devices -ScriptBlock {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force}
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

If there is a more practical way to do this please let me know if this is over-complicating a simple situation

Comment: I would say the best way to set this on many machines is to [use group policy, not a script](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/).

Comment: @briantist will give this a shot and respond soon thanks.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Scope MachinePolicy`?

Comment: Err, yup, Group Policy is the way forward.  Also useful for deploying profile scripts...

Comment: Confirmed that @briantist suggestion is the best possible method. All others work too in this case. Please post the answer if you'd like credit.

Comment: @Badlarry I would, but it would amount to a link-only answer, or I would include the steps, which is more appropriate for [sf], so I'm not quite sure what to do. I would think deleting/closing the question? Having trouble resolving this one haha.

Comment: @briantist well, sorry about that... I suppose I could close the question so if some one else has the same question they could see this. Anyways thanks again Brian....

Comment: @Badlarry no need to be sorry, you started with a code problem then got a solution that sort of makes the question not about code; it's perfectly reasonable I'm just not certain what to do with it.  Maybe ask on meta?

Comment: @briantist Meta created: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343225/asked-a-question-on-code-and-received-an-applicable-answer-for-server-fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is generally to [use Group Policy to set execution policy](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/) on a number of  machines.

From the link:

> To configure, navigate under Computer Configuration to
>   `Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell`
>   You should see a setting called **Turn on Script Execution**